# selecting minimum value depending on other value

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Is there any better way for below sql query? Don't want to drop and create temporary table just would like to do it in 1 query.
I am trying to select minimum value for price depending if its order sell where obviously price is higher then in buy and it just shows 0 results when I try it.

```
DROP TABLE `#temporary_table`;
CREATE TABLE `#temporary_table` (ID int(11),region int(11),nazwa varchar(100),price float,isBuyOrder int,volumeRemain int,locationID int,locationName varchar(100),systemID int,security_status decimal(1,1));
INSERT INTO `#temporary_table` SELECT * FROM hauling WHERE isBuyOrder=0 ORDER BY ID;
SELECT * FROM `#temporary_table`;
SELECT * FROM `#temporary_table` WHERE (ID,price) IN (select ID, MIN(price) from `#temporary_table` group by ID) order by `ID`
```

UPDATE: when I try nvogel answer and checked profiling thats what I get:
Any chance to optimize this or different working way with 700k rows database?

[image]

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Comment: I try that just in phpMyadmin

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM hauling AS h
WHERE isBuyOrder = 0
AND price =
  (SELECT MIN(t.price)
   FROM hauling AS t
   WHERE t.isBuyOrder = 0
   AND t.ID = h.ID);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and it only works with small database and I have over 700k rows and it freeze with an error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a temporary table at all.  You can basically use your current logic:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM hauling h
WHERE h.isBuyOrder = 0 AND
      (h.id, h.price) IN (SELECT h2.id, MIN(h2.price)
                          FROM hauling h2
                          WHERE h2.isBuyOrder = 0
                         )
```

ORDER BY h.id

There are many other ways to write similar logic.  However, there is no need to rewrite the logic; you just need to include the comparison on `isBuyOrder` in the subquery.

Note that not all databases support `IN` with tuples.  If your database does not provide such support, then you would need to rewrite the logic.

Comment: it just return 0 results

Comment: @MarcinKostrzewa . . . This does exactly what your logic does with the temporary table.